# FAQ questions in sidebar redirect to Meta Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, mso-mse-split

The [FAQ sidebar on Meta Stack Overflow has been enabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240186/faq-sidebar-for-per-site-metas), but although the links *appear* to stay within `http://meta.stackoverflow.com` they really point to the [lower post ids that redirect to Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own).

To reproduce, go to the [Meta Stack Overflow homepage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and hover over the links under the *Frequently Asked* sidebar header. If you ignore the link to Stack Apps and the (non-existing) [open-source-advertising](/questions/tagged/open-source-advertising) tag, all those links redirect you to Meta Stack Exchange instead.

So, although we have a [Community FAQ of our own](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow), the sidebar links to the [central MSE FAQ page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites). We shouldn't be directing visitors away from our own Meta, lets keep them here for the frequently asked questions *for Stack Overflow*.

I can take care of the [open-source-advertising](/questions/tagged/open-source-advertising) tag, but can a moderator or developer please fix the other links?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Woops. I originally turned on the same sidebar that's used on MSE, which also includes [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) questions (which are redundant here, as they're also included in the bulletin).

Then I found a setting that *didn't* include the featured questions, and switched to that... Without really paying much more attention to it. Apparently, that option is thoroughly broken - so I've reverted back to FeaturedAndFAQ.